# Moving Wordpress site to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, security, http, ssl, https

Trying to move our Wordpress site over to using HTTPS and having difficulty doing so. It keeps redirecting to http:// 
I've already changed the admin urls in Settings to https:// and already downloaded Force HTTPS plugin for Wordpress and still to no avail. Am I missing anything? Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Here is the link [www.v2.com/blog](http://www.v2.com/blog)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plugin you tried, then adding this to your .htaccess

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "www.wordpress.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.wordpress.com
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Resetting permalinks might help also, go into the permalinks settings then click save without changing anything

https://modernthemes.net/documentation/resetting-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the site redirects to https, but now I am unable to access my posts. Internet Server Error..

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file                                                                            # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "v2blog.local"
ErrorDocument 403 https://v2blog.local
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Do you have a valid certificate for v2blog.local ? And did you try resetting permalinks? That step is important as WordPress may have cached your http links

Comment: Yes , i've reset permalinks and i've created a self-signed certificate for apache using this doc [link] (https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-ssl), currently the error in Chrome is saying "Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)". Maybe it was configured incorrectly? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to ignore the invalid certificate error and get through to the WP posts?

Comment: Nope, whenever I click on a post it displays 500 error : "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at ggalarza@v2.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: Apache error log displays the following: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://v2blog.local/

Comment: Update: Fixed the wp posts issue by adding modifying .htaccess to this:                                 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Somewhere along the line your posts are being redirected to https then back to http infinitely. You may need to comment out htaccess, change site URL, update permalinks, then uncomment htaccess. If that still fails you may need to manually find and replace in the MySQL